# uv project from view issue

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv, physics, uv-image-editor

As you can see, below are screenshots. The first one came from this video https://drive.google.com/file/d/1X9loKHE1Mi0N3oCKVxh5Eg6KV7S6s7km/view?usp=sharing and on the right side is the UV editor. So when he selects all the boxes in edit mode and select project from view all the cubes appear in the UV window but when I try that, only one cube appears even though all the cubes in edit mode are selected. No matter if there are 10 or 1000 cubes selected, the same cube is selected in the UV view and in the same place and rotation. All my cubes are copies from one original cube, so maybe that's why in UV view I only see the one cube selected. Maybe because I used a box and used the particle properties and filled the volume with the original object. I did that because that was a fast way to make duplicates, and also I can easily randomize their rotation and position. If there is another way I can do that besides an array, because I can't seem to get a scatter and random rotation effect with the array, let me know please.

[image]
[image]
[image]

I just noticed this. My original cube is not selectable and off the scene. So when I select only the cubes in the middle of the screen and enter edit mode and select all. It will for some reason select the original cube???

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this isn't doing what you want is that your objects are all *linked copies* of each other.  As linked copies, they share all mesh data, including UV.  So if you change the UV of one of them, you change the UV of all of them, *to the exact same UV.*

In order to do what you're after, you first need to unlink these objects, which you can do with "make single user-> object and data".  This should be accessible from your search menu (I use 'u' but likely have different interface setup than you, and I believe this is someplace where that matters.)

Now, in your file, when I do that, Blender crashes.  I haven't troubleshooted the cause of that, and figure it could easily be down to some differences between your setup and mine (including possibly Blender version differences.)

However, it's still what you need to do.   Once you have unlinked these objects, they will be able to each take their own unique UV for your project from view.

Comment: I'll have to try that out. When I use that "make single user" do I need to check all these boxes or leave the one checked only checked. https://ibb.co/RzvJCSq I'm sure it will definitely fail on my laptop if it crashed for you. I may have to remove half the cubes. I'll try this on a test run before I go back to the big project. What you suggested worked, but now there are other issues. The cubes don't change their rotations when they settle down, so many are standing on their corners. Also, the logo isn't being projected onto the cubes still. Could that be because each side already has a color

Comment: Assigned to its face? https://ibb.co/KbZ5yXc Also, when I have them selected in the UV view I tried to scale it, so the logo will fit on the cubes but when I go to scale the selected faces it's doing some weird stuff. And I don't know what the black pieces are that are left in their place. https://ibb.co/cXhcRTY

Comment: @adlowe07 Sorry, Stack Exchange just isn't the right place to troubleshoot a series of problems that you're having; they quickly stop being relevant to the question asked, and SE makes conversation impossible.  I would recommend posting elsewhere.  blenderartists.org would be a good place where people would probably be able to help with further problems you're having.